# Controlling wave amplitude by arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, digital-logic, analog, digital-potentiometer

I built waveform generator using AD9833. It can produce sine and triangular wave with amplitude about 1.6 V and square wave with amplitude of 4.5 V. I'm searching for some circuit which can control amplitude of output wave and this amplitude can be set by arduino so something like PWM should be used.

In conclusion I am searching for a circuit which has:

First input - square, triangle or sine signal, frequency 1Hz to 1MHz. Signal is produced by AD9833. Its impedance should be 200 Ohms. Amplitude is 1.6 V for sine and triangle and 4.5 V for square.

Second input - signal from arduino about set amplitude

Wanted output - input signal with modified amplitude between 0 - 12 V. This output amplitude should be set by arduino.

I would like to hear some ideas which circuit should I use. I'm still a beginner and I need your help. Thanks for reply. I look forward to your ideas for solving my problem.

Comment: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.* - also you are borderline making a shopping question and that is disallowed on this site. Sorry. You have also not provided enough technical information about the signals you wish to regulate/amplify/control in terms of frequency, DC offsets, source impedances etc..

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for reply. I  am going to actualise my question in a moment.

Comment: Do you mean fix it?

Comment: @Andyaka edited. Is it ok now?

Comment: There are potentially hundreds of ways to answer this question. Please clarify what you are asking. Providing a shopping list of potential circuits is not what this site is supposed to be about. You should read up on voltage controlled amplifiers and then try to reform your question to something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Classic answer : Multiplying DAC or MDAC, e.g. AD7528 (with two channels).

Apply audio input to the reference voltage pin. The output is a current, feeding an opamp in inverting configuration as an I-V converter.

Controlling the DAC's digital inputs then controls the gain of the analog input signal.

More [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246271/digitaly-controlled-voltage-divider-for-picky-audio-recording-enthousiasts/246299#246299)